# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined! WEBPACK AND BABEL ERROR

Tags: zlib, webpack-4, babel-loader, node.js-fs, webpack-config

my MERN project has some errors ("zlib" Module not found  etc..), because of that, i added some codes in module.exports={ resolve:{....}} on my webpack.config.js file in my react node moduse folder (node_modules\react-scripts\config).

```
 resolve: {

      fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "crypto": false , //require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "net": require.resolve("net-browserify"),
      },
}
```

And i gave an error again on console: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined. I cant solve it. Please help me!

All codes in github : https://github.com/hanifeyolat/Uncaught-ReferenceError--process-is-not-defined/tree/main